# How do I get the value of radio button option in my Knockout.js wizard?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, radio-button, wizard, knockout-templating

To simplify things, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FyuSD/157/

```
<script id="choiceTmpl" type="text/html">
            <label><input type="radio" value="boughtBefore" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Purchase products I have bought before</label>
            <br />
            <label><input type="radio" value="searchProduct" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />Search for a product I haven't purchased before</label>
            <br />
```

I guess I have a couple questions. I am building a wizard and need different execution steps depending on which option the user selects. The question I want to know is, how do I get the value of radio button that they select?

Like on step two, if they select "purchase products I have bought before" how can I redirect it to another question: create order from guide or create order from previous order (using radio buttons again)?

I can't figure out how to get the value of what they select. **Furthermore, how would I skip steps** depending on the option they choose? (fore example, go from step 2 to step 4 if they select "want to search for a product" in step 2)

Lastly, is there an easy way to change the radio-button text to match the questions without create a new template for each?

Sorry if this is too many questions, and thanks for the help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The value of the radio button they check is passed to the function (typically an observable, setting its value) by the checked binding. See the [radio example in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).
2. Set up a computed as a state machine, and then have its value determine which wizard page is visible.
3. Label text could also be bound to model properties, but I didn't do that in my example.

I've written a simplistic example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqt46qw1/
Note that although my example uses only the radio selection to determine the page to show, your computed can involve as many variables as you need it to.

```
<div data-bind="visible:wizPage() == '1'">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <label>Page 2</label><input type="radio" value="p2" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
    <label>Page 3</label><input type="radio" value="p3" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
</div>
<div data-bind="visible:wizPage() == '2'">
    <h1>Some Option</h1>
    <label>Page 3</label><input type="radio" value="p3" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
    <label>Start Over</label><input type="radio" value="p1" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
</div>
<div data-bind="visible:wizPage() == '3'">
    <h1>Another Option</h1>
    <label>Page 2</label><input type="radio" value="p2" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
    <label>Start Over</label><input type="radio" value="p1" data-bind="checked:radioSelected" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = (function () {
    var radioSelected = ko.observable();
    var wizPage = ko.computed(function () {
        if (radioSelected() == 'p2') {
            return '2';
        }
        else if (radioSelected() == 'p3') {
            return '3';
        }
        else {
            return '1';
        }
    });
    return {
        wizPage: wizPage,
        radioSelected:radioSelected
    };
}());

console.debug("ViewModel:", viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a much better way to implement in and removes the stupid templating I was trying to do.